# Running Total Concrete Cubic Yardage Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a calculator that does the following.

- Accept Length, Width, and Height value.
- Multiply the Width by 12 because it needs to be converted to feet.
- Then Length Width and Height are multiplied together and divided by
  27.
- That total should then be displayed in the text box. I would then like to keep that as a running total but that's where I'm having the problem. For some reason its only adding once and then stopping.

```js
var wallTotal = 0;

function addWall() {
  var inHeight = document.getElementById("inHgt").value
  var inWidth = document.getElementById("inWid").value
  var inLength = document.getElementById("inLen").value
  inWidth = inWidth / 12
  wallTotal = (parseFloat(inHeight * inWidth * inLength) / 27);
  document.getElementById("outWall").value = wallTotal;
}
```

```html
<h1>House</h1>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <p>Height: <input type="text" name="inHgt" id="inHgt" /></p>
  <p>Width: <input type="text" name="inWid" id="inWid" /></p>
  <p>Length: <input type="text" name="inLen" id="inLen" /></p>
  <p>Cubic Yards of Concrete: <input type="text" name="outWall" id="outWall" /></p>
</form>
<p>
  <input type="button" id="addIn" value="Add That Wall" onclick="addWall()" />
</p>
```

Comment: Not what you're asking, but why is it only width that needs to be converted to feet? Shouldn't the fields be labelled with "inches" or "feet" so that the user knows what to enter? (Also, you mean *divide*, not multiply.)

Comment: You don't need `parseFloat` here, because the multiplication already coerces the strings to numbers.

Comment: @4castle - And even `*` didn't coerce, `parseFloat()` would need to be used on the individual values *before* multiplying, not on the result.

Comment: You have to divide by 12 because it is going to be inputted in inches. When you're building concrete walls you'll usually be working with walls that have a width of 8 inches 10 inches or 12 inches.

Comment: I don't know-- I don't think it's the worst idea in the world to parseFloat strings you want to treat as numbers-- just to avoid running into any unexpected conversion strangeness.  But nnnnnn is right-- have to do it on the individual values first-- otherwise it's not necessarily accomplishing much.  And finally-- when using parseInt or parse float, don't forget to include the "optional" (but highly recommended) "radix" arg [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Also I removed parsefloat thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is you are overwriting `wallTotal` every time your `addWall()` function runs.  You just need to add to the total instead:

```
wallTotal += (parseFloat(inHeight*inWidth*inLength)/27);
```

Note the `+=` operator, which is shorthand for:

```
wallTotal = wallTotal + (parseFloat(inHeight*inWidth*inLength)/27);
```

Comment: YES! I've been trying to figure this out for 12 hours or more you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Glad to hear this solved it for you!  If Daniel Bank's answer worked for you, you should select it as the right answer so he gets some reputation for it, and others visiting the page no which solution worked for you.  Happy coding!